# R generate number (Id) along sequence using two different vectors, lapply?

Tags: r, vector, row, lapply

I have two vectors, which are basically starting and ending Row indices.
I want to group them using this vectors.
Example

```
a<-c(1,4,7,12)
b<-c(3,6,11,15)
```

my output vector should be

```
d <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rep` to repeat value `b-a` times.

```
rep(seq_along(a), (b - a) + 1)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this work:

```
> rep(1:length(a), c(b[1],diff(b)))
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
rep(seq_len(length(a)), (b - a) + 1)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```